# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: cypress

This is my code

```js
describe('Demo', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.fixture('example.json').then(function (data) {
      this.data = data
    })
  })
  it('Fixture demo', () => {
    cy.visit('https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/login')
    cy.get('input[name=Email]').clear().type(this.data.email)
    cy.get('input[name=Password]').clear().type(this.data.password)
    cy.get('.login-button').click()
  })
})
```

Error is showing in this line

```js
cy.get('input[name=Email]').clear().type(this.data.email)
                                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix please change arrow functions `() => {` to non-arrow functions `function() {`.

If using `this` you need to use `function()`.

```js
before(function() {
  cy.fixture('example.json').then(function(data){
    this.data=data
  })
})

it('Fixture demo', function() {
  cy.visit('https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/login')
  cy.get('input[name=Email]').clear().type(this.data.email)
  ...
})
```

Comment: It is also not working for me

Comment: You are doing something wrong, I get `hello@cypress.io` from `this.data.email`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused with component class approach, Cypress test file is not a class file, you shouldn't use `this` keyword here

To fix this you can declare a global variable for your data and use it later in your tests

```js
describe('Demo', () => {
  let exampleData; //Create variable here

  before(() => {
    cy.fixture('example.json').then(function (data) {
      exampleData = data //Assign data here
    })
  })
  it('Fixture demo', () => {
    cy.visit('https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/login')
    cy.get('input[name=Email]').clear().type(exampleData.email) //Use it like this
    cy.get('input[name=Password]').clear().type(exampleData.password) //Use it like this
    cy.get('.login-button').click()
  })
})
```